# Installing OSMC as an executable instead of OS

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, operating-systems, osmc

I'm using the RPi3 with one SD-card. I run Raspbian Jessie Lite from it and use it to build several projects.

Recently I wanted to start using the same Pi as a mini media server. I think I'll really like OSMC, but I can only install it as a separate operating system, and I want to keep the Raspbian as my OS, without GUI.

Instead, I want to be able to start OSMC from the terminal in Raspbian.

Is that possible? If not, what is the best alternative I can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OSMC` is basically an OS which runs `Kodi` on boot.

You can install `Kodi` as a stand alone program under Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing magical about OSMC; it just prepackages all the executables you need to run a media center, and gives you a nice interface. IIRC, it is based on Debian, so you have two options:

1. Study the installed packages, startup scripts, configuration files, and so on, of OSMC, and just duplicate those on your vanilla Raspbian installation. You will learn a lot in the process!
2. Move all your project files from the vanilla Raspbian to OSMC (it's also Debian, remember?) and keep working that way!